# How do I dynamically create channel using agora.io

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, agora.io

I'm building a multivendor website in wordpress for webinars and classes and I´m using Dokan plugin. I want to use meetings as products of my vendors...

So this is what I thought:
When user[a] signs up for an account on mywebsite.com, agora.io API creates a channel with the username that will come from user[a] account, and then produce a response containing (appid, token, channel) relevant information.

When user[a] logs into mywebsite.com, their agora.io API (appid, token, channel) relevant information automatically populate:

```
var appID = 'user[a]app1D';
var Token = 'user[a]t0k3n';
var channel = 'user[a]channel';
```

Your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at the [Agora Video for Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-agora-io/?src=medium-quickstart) and use the [QuickStart Guide](https://medium.com/agora-io/agora-video-for-wordpress-plugin-quickstart-guide-b8838abd4245) to make sure it is set up correctly.

The Agora Video for Wordpress plugin does not automatically create the channels in the manner with which have have described, but you could easily add that functionality to your WordPress instance.

When a user creates an account, you would want to create a new Agora Channel, this will provide the channel ID. Then create a page with the Agora shortcode and pass the channel ID.

Answer (score 0):

Nico, i'm facing the same problem, and find a solution.
The AGORA channels are posts like any other.

You will need to:

1. Create a post with post_type: agora_channel
2. Update all post_meta required by AGORA

i've solved with this:

```
$id = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_title'=>'Channel of' . $user->display_name, 
        'post_type'=>'agora_channel', 
        'post_content' => ''
    ));

    if(!is_wp_error($id)){

        update_post_meta($id, 'channel_appearance_settings', array(
            'external-rtmpServerURL' => '',
            'external-streamKey' => '',
            'external-width' => 640,
            'external-height' => 360,
            'external-videoBitrate' => 400,
            'external-videoFramerate' => 15,
            'external-videoGop' => 30,
            'external-lowLatency' => false,
            'external-audioSampleRate' => 48000,
            'external-audioBitrate' => 48,
            'external-audioChannels' => 1,
            'external-videoCodecProfile' => 100,
            'external-backgroundColor' => '#efefef',
            'inject-width' => 640,
            'inject-height' => 360,
            'inject-videoBitrate' => 400,
            'inject-videoFramerate' => 15,
            'inject-videoGop' => 30,
            'inject-lowLatency' => false,
            'inject-audioSampleRate' => 48000,
            'inject-audioBitrate' => 48,
            'inject-audioChannels' => 1,
            'inject-videoCodecProfile' => 100,
            'inject-backgroundColor' => '#efefef',
            )
        );

        update_post_meta($id, 'channel_appearance_settings', array(
            'splashImageURL' => "",
            'noHostImageURL' => '',
            'watchButtonText' => '',
            'watchButtonIcon' => false,
            'activeButtonColor' => '#343a40',
            'disabledButtonColor' => '#dc3545',
        ));
        
        update_post_meta($id, 'channel_type','broadcast');
        

        update_post_meta($id, 'channel_appearance_settings', array(
            'splashImageURL' => '',
            'noHostImageURL' => '',
            'watchButtonText' => '',
            'watchButtonIcon' => true,
            'activeButtonColor' => '#fdb911',
            'disabledButtonColor' => '#bfbfbf'
            )
        );
        update_post_meta($id, 'channel_user_host', $user->ID);
    }
```